# How many automorphisms are in $Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, automorphism-group

I came across this question on [brilliant](https://brilliant.org). I first observed that any particular automorphism (i.e., a bijective homomorphism) must map each group element to a distinct element in the group set: if it were to map two elements to the same one, the inverse of the automorphism wouldn't exist. Therefore we can create a candidate automorphism by permuting the group elements (every permutation is invertible).

Then, we can find the group operation of the automorphism $f$ as follows: $\forall x, y \in f(G): x \cdot y = f(f^{-1}(x)) \cdot f(f^{-1}(y)) = f(f^{-1}(x) * f^{-1}(y))$. (The inverse exists because it is bijective and the last equality is the definition of homomorphisms.)

Subsequently I verified that $f(G)$ obeys associativity, identity and invertibility, and thus is indeed a group. In fact, this holds for every permutation (if my python code is correct).

Lastly, I observed that no two permutations lead to the same automorphism, therefore there is no double counting.

I thus came to the conclusion that there are $|Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2|! = 8! = 40320$ automorphisms.

According to the [brilliant](https://brilliant.org) though, the correct answer is 168. The justification there is:

> An automorphism is determined uniquely by what elements the three
> generators $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ turn into under the map.
> The first one can turn into any of seven nontrivial elements. The
> second one can turn into any of six elements (not the identity and not
> what $(1,0,0)$ turned into). The third one can turn into any of four
> elements (it can't turn into any of the four elements generated by the
> images of the first two generators). So, the answer is $7 \cdot 6 \cdot 4 = 168$.
>
> In fact, the automorphism group is $GL_3({\mathbb F}_2)$, the group of
> with coefficients in $\{0, 1\}$ modulo $2$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: An automorphism must satisfy the rule $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb{Z}_2\times \Bbb{Z}_2\times\Bbb{Z}_2$. Otherwise $f$ will not be a *homomorphism.*

Comment: Automorphisms are permutations but not all permutations are automorphism. You counted the permutations but forgot to check which of them were automorphisms.

Comment: And consider that $(0,0,0)$ is kept fixed by any automorphism... so at least the sought number is $\le 7!$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I believe that OP understands this, they just thought that they could define $+$ differently in the image from in the domain.

Comment: @NicholasPriebe I see. Then the question makes more sense. Well spotted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve made a subtle but very understandable mistake. You found the number of bijections from $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ where you could put the group structure of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ on the image; however automorphisms don’t come with group structures, you need to work with the already existing one. For example, your definition would consider the map $f$ that swaps $(0, 0, 0)$ and ($1, 0, 0)$ and fixes everything else to be a valid automorphism. However, that map isn’t, since $f((0, 0, 0) + (0, 1, 0)) \neq f(0, 0, 0) + f(0, 1, 0)$.

The + on both sides needs to be doing the same thing for this to be an automorphism! More generally, for any homomorphism $g : G \to H$, you need $G$ and $H$ to already have group structured and for $\phi$ to respect the existing structure, not define a new one.

Comment: Why do the two group operations ($+_G$ and $+_{f(G)}$) need to coincide?

Comment: Because $f(G)$ is $G$ in the case of an automorphism, by definition. An automorphism is a bijective homomorphism from $G$ to $G$. More generally, a homomorphism starts with a choice of two groups, so you have two fixed group structures, and the homomorphism must respect them, by $f(x +_{G} y) = f(x) +_{H} f(y)$ — but when you ask about homomorphism from $G$ to $H$, $+_{G}$ and $+_{H}$ are already defined! In the case of an Automorphism, $G = H$.

Comment: So IIUC the property I wasn't maintaining was that of endomorphism. My construction selected all bijective homomorphisms from $Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2$ to _some_ (not necessarily constant) group with the same elements but with a different operation, right?

Comment: Yep, exactly! Glad I could help